PDF corrupted after downloading with Python Requests
I need to download a file from one of those links with python, but the pdf won't open after downloaded.
https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=693676
https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/downloadDocumento?id=693676
import requests

i = ["https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=693676", "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/downloadDocumento?id=693676"]

l =0
for k in i:
    l += 1
    user_agent = "scrapping_script/1.0"
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    download = requests.get(k, headers=headers)
    with open(f"/Users/renato/Documents/{l}.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(download.content)

I already tried using urllib and changing the headers, but had the same issue. Any suggestions? Thanks!

first open this PDF file in normal text editor - maybe you get HTML with warning for scrapers or with Captcha.

for server may need User-Agent from real web browser and "scrapping_script/1.0" can block access to data.

your code doesn't work for me - it show error because of SSL Verification so I have to add verify=False.

If I display downloaded file (in normal text editor, or in console) then I see string with characteristic == at the end which suggests that it file encoded with base64 - so it needs
import base64

content = base64.b64decode(download.content)

That's all

Full working code which I used for tests.
I had to add verify=False because of problem with SSL verification.
import base64
import requests

items = [
    "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=693676", 
    "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/downloadDocumento?id=693676"
]

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "scrapping_script/1.0",
    #'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0",
}

for index, url in enumerate(items, 1):
    print('url:', url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    
    #for key, val in response.headers.items():
    #    print(f'{key}: {val}')
    if 'Content-Disposition' in response.headers:
        print('Content-Disposition:', response.headers['Content-Disposition'])
        filename = response.headers['Content-Disposition'].split('filename=')[-1].strip('"')
        print('filename:', filename)
    
    content = base64.b64decode(response.content)
    #print(content)
    
    #filename = f"/Users/renato/Documents/{index:02}.pdf" 
    filename = f"{index:02}.pdf" 
    print('filename:', filename)
    
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)

